# Mahr Ur ungespundet recipe

Tags: recipe

I'm looking for a [Mahr's Ur](http://www.mahrs.de/en/beer/mahrs-braeu-ungespundet-hefetrueb-unfiltered-yeast-turbid/) recipe.

Any ideas?

Comment: Brewing / Class: Bottom-fermented “Vollbier”
Brewing Law: Bavarian Purity Law of 1516
Raw ingredients: The finest pale Pilsner & Munich malt, Hallertauer Perle aromatic hops
Original gravity: approx. 12.7%
Alcohol by volume (ABV): approx. 5.2%

the description they give on the site, posted above, gives you a good starting point. but you may want to look other places for specific recipes.

Comment: Yes, I was just looking for pale Pilsner to Munich malt ratios, some hints on which aromatic hops i might need to use, and some hints on the process (e.g. its an "ungespundet" beer, that is, no bung, or open fermentation). Do you know of any other place I could look for recipes? My google-fu fails me.

Comment: personally i would start, with 5% to 10% munich malt, the rest pale pilsner.
I would also only do a 60 min bittering hop, and a flame out for flavor aromatics, but only a little. Hop choice should be any german noble hop, but perle would be best for the a clone.

Answer (score 1):

well doing some reading, i have to say ignore my last comment. 
I made a quick recipe for myself, that may or may not be close to what being a clone of the link above, but it does look good....and will be brewing this probably in the next few months. (FYI i have no idea what "Mahrs Ur" tastes like)
(inspiration for this [is this recipe](https://byo.com/stories/issue/item/1808-german-pilsner))

my interpertation is,

50% pilsner malt (6lb)

50% munich malt (6lb)

hallertau hops, 1oz 60min

hallertau hops  .25oz flame out

Saflager W-24/70 (est attenuation up to 83%)

OG 1.051

FG 1.009

ABV 5.6

IBU(rager)19.8

Efficency 70%

full body mash schedule

(Recipe is for 5 gals, on my system)